# Verificar valor en propiedad de string antes de enviarlo a una base de datos

Tags: php, json, string

Buen dia, la duda en cuestión es la siguiente.

Estoy creando un sistema al que se le cargan recetas. Una receta esta formada por ingredientes. Tengo un formulario donde primero coloco el nombre del ingrediente, luego selecciono el cliente, y abajo tengo un botón `Agregar Ingrediente`.

Cuando hago click en este botón se renderiza una `row` que tiene un `select` para elegir el nombre del ingrediente, luego un input para seleccionar la cantidad, y otros dos inputs `readonly` donde va la unidad de medida del ingrediente, y el precio (que se forma multiplicando el precio del ingrediente por la cantidad).

Cuando termino de cargar el menú, doy click al botón `Guardar Menú`, y se envía a mi base de datos todos los datos de dicho menú. Entre ellos, un `string` formado por todos los ingredientes, que es algo como esto:

```
[
 {"ingrediente":"Papas","cantidad":"1","unidad":"Kg","precio":"19"}, 
 {"ingrediente":"Carne Picada","cantidad":"1","unidad":"Kg","precio":"100"}, 
 {"ingrediente":"Sal Fina","cantidad":"0.1","unidad":"Kg","precio":"4.2"}
]
```

Me gustaría comprobar que la cantidad de cualquier ingrediente no pueda ser igual a 0 antes de enviar, y por una cuestión de cómo se generan diatónicamente los inputs, no me sirve comprobarlo al finalizar de cargar cada ingrediente, sino en el momento que se va a guardar el menú.

Quisiera saber si tengo algún método sencillo en `PHP` que recorra el `string`
(o de ultima lo paso a `json` y que recorra el objeto) y se fije en cada una de las propiedades `"cantidad"`, y pueda encontrar si algún valor es igual a cero.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

1. Crear un json con los datos
2. Crear una variable establecida a `FALSE` por defecto
3. Verificar en un bucle `foreach` si el valor de `cantidad` es igua a `0` en cuyo caso cambiaríamos el valor de `$hasZero` a `TRUE` y saldríamos del bucle con `break`. Así ganamos en rendimiento, porque no tiene sentido seguir recorriendo los otros datos
4. Usar `$hasZero` para lo que quieras...

Ejemplo:

```
$str='
[
 {"ingrediente":"Papas","cantidad":"1","unidad":"Kg","precio":"19"}, 
 {"ingrediente":"Carne Picada","cantidad":"1","unidad":"Kg","precio":"100"}, 
 {"ingrediente":"Sal Fina","cantidad":"0.1","unidad":"Kg","precio":"4.2"}
]
';
$json=json_decode($str);
$hasZero=FALSE;
foreach ($json as $item){
    if($item->cantidad==0) {
        $hasZero=TRUE;
    break; #Salimos del bucle
    }
}
var_dump($hasZero); #Para probar... borrar

#Usar $hasZero ...
```

**Salida:**

Cuando haya un 0:

```
bool(true)
```

Cuando no haya un 0:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Gracias crack! Salio con fritas a caballo =)